# How do I access class variable from a second script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to check the ever changing values of `TEST.Loop` and change
`TEST.Delay` value while the loop is running (`def Work():`)?

I can make an
instance of `TEST`, and change it for other instance of `TEST`, but I can't find a
way to look at any of the values inside the `Work` loop and change of variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from time import sleep 

class TEST:
    Test = 0
    Loop = 0
    Delay =.1

    def inc_delay(self):
        TEST.Delay += 1
        print ( 'inc called' , TEST.Delay )

    def dec_delay(self):
        TEST.Delay -+ 1

    def Work():
        while TEST.Loop < 10000:
            TEST.Loop += 1
            sleep( TEST.Delay )
            print ( TEST.Loop , TEST.Delay )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TEST.Work()
```

The second script is something like:

```
import class_filename
a = class_filename.TEST
a.Delay = whatever
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. what do you mean by a second script here? the other process?? can you provide better example code?

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy.when you want to acses somthing fromm inside a cllass when you are in that class you just name it unless you are in a function.then you would pretend you are outside the class
when you want to acsess somthin inside a class you use the following syntax when you are in the same file but outside the class:

```
ClassNameThisIsNotAKeyWord.AtributeCanBeAFunction
```

in a sepret file you would use

```
moudule_name.ClassNameThisIsNotAKeyWord.AtributeCanBeAFunction
```

:)